# Laravel how to ignore empty parameter numbers

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a laravel application, Here i can 'filter' out my 'files' first by role (assigned to the user), Folder and then subfolders. for the query i use a for loop, but this can return different values depending on the 'filters' i use.
Now laravel returns this error message:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Query:

```
select * from `file` where `id` in (8, 12, 13, ?, ?, ?)
```

Now i want to ignore those '?' and keep it from returning an error, i know this is doable by making the '?' NULL. but i cant find a way to do that

the code:

```
 public function show($id)
    {
   
        $user = Auth::user();
        $userid = $user->id;
        $role_id = $user->role_id;
        $folders = Folder::all();
        $file_role = File_Role::where('role_id', '=', $role_id)->pluck('file_id');
    //    dd($file_role[1]);
    $count = count($file_role);
    $i = 0;
 
  
    var_dump($file_role);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
          
        $file[] = File_Subfolder::where('subfolder_id', '=', $id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id');
        
        }  

        $chosenfile = File::whereIn('id', $file)->get();
        
        return view('partner.subquents.sub_file', compact('chosenfile'));
    }
```

$file returns 8,12,13,?,?,? in this case. this can change depending on the filters

i tried an foreach loop.and i tried to find on the internet how to assign NULL to '?' values

as you can see in my DD that some dont give data back, but some do

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try this:

```
$fileSubFolderCount = File_Subfolder::where('subfolder_id', '=', $id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id')->count();
$file[] = $fileSubFolderCount > 0 ? File_Subfolder::where('subfolder_id', '=', $id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id') : null;
```